# Panel Size not staying the same between two computers in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity for a group project, on one computer we get everything set up and looking nice, but after pushing to GitHub and opening on a personal computer the screen size seems to be smaller and buttons are off the panel. Is there a setting that we are missing?

[image]

Personal computer view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

This is happening because you are both using absolute positioning in your Rect Transform, and not properly nesting the Back/Main Menu/? buttons inside your panel in the Scene hierarchy (leftmost panel).

Depending on your specific need, I would either make Nav a child of the panel, if you want your Nav buttons to be inside your panel, or else change your Rect Transform anchor presets for Nav to something like "Stretch Top" rather than "Center Center".

Generally, you want to use "stretch" with dimensions that are screen-dependent (e.g. "this nav area should always span the width of the screen"). For things that are not screen-dependent (e.g. "this nav button should always be 5 pixels below the top of the screen"), it's okay to use manual position values.

### Long Answer

There are two primary means of positioning under the hood in Unity:

- Anchors
- Pixel Offsets

#### Anchors

Anchors essentially define the element's relation to its parent. Some examples:

- The default anchor of Min: (.5, .5), Max: (.5, .5) means that the element's position will be calculated from the x-center and y-center of the parent element.
- An anchor of Min: (0, .5), Max: (0, .5) means that the element's position will be calculated from the midpoint of the parent's left edge.
- An anchor of Min: (1, 1), Max: (1, 1) means that the element's position will be calculated from the parent's top-right corner.

Note that all of the example anchors so far have had the same minimum and maximum values, resulting in an anchor that is a single point. If you set the minimum and maximum values differently, it will instead create an anchor "box" that the element will scale to fill. Some examples of this:

- An anchor of Min: (0, 0), Max: (1, 1) means that the element will scale to be the same size as the parent.
- An anchor of Min: (0, 0), Max: (.5, .5) means that the element will
  scale to fill the bottom-left quarter of the parent.
- An anchor of Min: (0, 0), Max: (1, .5) means that the element will
  scale to fill the bottom half of the parent.

#### Pixel Offsets

Now that we understand anchors, what are pixel offsets? Essentially, they are absolute pixel positional offsets from the edges of the anchors. For example:

- An anchor of Min: (0, 0), Max: (.5, .5) and pixel offset of Top: 40 Right: 10 means that the element will scale to fill the bottom-left quarter of the parent, and then additionally scale to fill 40 pixels above the vertical midpoint of the screen and 10 pixels to the right of the horizontal midpoint of the screen.

### Hey, I don't have any pixel offsets!

Yes you do, but the Unity inspector pane uses different terminology for them depending on how your anchors are set up. You'll see "Top", "Left", "Right", and "Bottom" only if you have your anchors set to make a rectangle rather than a point. Otherwise, you may see fields like "Pos X", "Pos Y", "Width", or "Height". However, these fields are merely conceptual abstractions for offsets. For example, setting "Width" to 100 is equivalent to setting "Left" to -50 and "Right" to 50, and so on.

## Great, how should I use these?

Generally, use anchor boxes to create responsive layouts, then use offsets inside those layout boxes to fine-tune positions.